# Slick.js remove gap on first and last slide when centerMode is true and infinite is false

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Using slick.js with `centerMode: true` and `infinite: false` currently will be leaving a gap on the left on the first slide, and a gap on the right side on the last slide. https://jsfiddle.net/qyfxh52k/11/

I've searched around for this and what I've found on this was that the author feels like centerMode should never be used when infinite is false. https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/2808

Is there any way for me to do this without having the gap, an example of what i'm looking for is something like https://ishimoto-demo.squarespace.com/ where centermode is only active on other slides that are not the first nor the last.

I've tried initing the slick without the centermode, and re-initing it on slide change with the centermode, however this would cause a jump and isn't really ideal. What would be the best way for me to handle this?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: No i did not. I have decided to scrap the slider alltogether and went with a different design in the end.

Comment: I have this problem too(( and i dont find escape

Answer (score 0):

I have this variant - https://codepen .io/Nikolasgrizli/pen/dybRpxY (remove space after "codepen", but I dont like how this works.